# Change the format of datepicker

Tags: datepicker, uitextfield

How can I change the format of a date to `yy/mm/dd`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if (textField == _celebration)
  {
      UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
      [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
      [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
      [self.celebration setInputView:datePicker];
  }
}

- (void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
  UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.celebration.inputView;
  self.celebration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a formatter like this

```
NSDateFormatter* format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"YY/MM/dd"];
```

Get the formatted string from a an NSDate like this

```
NSString* testDate = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Get an NSDate back from a string like so.

```
NSDate* reformDate = [format dateFromString:testDate];
```

Release if not in ARC, otherwise set to nil
    [format release]; or format = nil;

You could modify your function to look something like this. This would set the formatted date string as your UITextField's text.

```
- (void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.celebration.inputView;

    NSDateFormatter* format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"YY/MM/dd"];

    NSString* formattedDate = [format stringFromDate:picker.date];

    self.celebration.text = formattedDate;

    format = nil;
}
```

That being said The UIDatePicker itself doesn't support formatting like this. You can reference the class here. 
[UIDatePicker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

If you are really set on this format for a datePicker you would probably have to build a custom one. However, I would discourage this since the built in UIDatepicker takes a user's Locale and language into consideration automatically while your format would lock it into your preferred format (which isn't always correct for your user depending on where they are in the world).

Comment: thanks , where exactly should I make a connection between datePicker and result from NSDateFormatter(reformDate) in the attached code?

Comment: Sorry John, I mis-understood the question. I have edited my answer to address the title of the question as well. I read the content earlier and didn't take the title into account.

Comment: Is there any better solution to create the UIDatePicker for UITextField and assign the mentione format to the textfiled?

Comment: Sure, if you just want to display the formatted date in the text field. Then in your - (void)updateTextField:(id)sender method, format the date that you get from the picker and set the text field's text with the formatted date. I will add that above as well.

Comment: thanks, but 1)what I'm getting from this is a datepicker with the format like : Feb 19 7 03 AM. when I'm clicking on a datepicker for the first time the textfield is changing with the today's date(13/02/20) not the date on the datepicker.

Comment: Ok, check the new example again. I was still using the [NSDate date] instead of the date on the picker. That is now changed to picker.date. Also, if you are just looking for the date from the datePicker you can set the mode on it like this [picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];